# Remove group indicator when use a CursorTreeAdapter for a ExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview

Is there an API or any official way to remove the group indicator for the item which does not has children when use a CursorTreeAdapter for a ExpandableListView?

Help! thanks a lot.

Comment: I have tried to set a state list drawble to GroupIndicator. It doesn't work.

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611927/simplecursortreeadapter-and-cursorloader

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I struggled with this thing for a long time, the way I ended up doing it was to hide completely the GroupIndicator from the ExpandableListView

```
  <ExpandableListView android:id="@+id/android:list"
android:layout_below="@id/technical_details_label_separator"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
android:groupIndicator="@android:color/transparent"
/>
```

Then I created a Custom adapter extending BaseExpandableListAdapter, and implemented the  getGroupView method, inside this method you can create a View with an ImageView that you can switch manually to expand or contract the group (using the isExpanded flag), and hide it completely if the group was empty.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListAdapter.html#getGroupView(int, boolean, android.view.View, android.view.ViewGroup)

Comment: Thanks, jucas. It's a good workaround. but if so, we cann't use the system default look and feel of the group indicator.

Comment: yep, that is true...but as I said other solutions didn't work for me. I tried a stateList drawable, but the main issue with it is that an "empty" group is the same as a non-expanded group.

I copied the group indicator drawables from the SDK data into my project to at least offer the system default look for some devices

Comment: jucas, have you tried to use a sub class which extends CursorTreeAdapter? Your solution doesn't work in that case.

Comment: Lei, I haven't tried that I guess the CursorTreeAdapter draws it itself anyway